# AXE - Asp Xtreme Evolution - Json parser for classic asp

Tags: json, asp-classic, vbscript

Has anyone ever used this and got it working?  I'm having real problems because it's telling me there is a JScript error and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Links on this are here to get some background on the product, but it's a JSON parser for classic asp.
[Iterating though a JSON return using ASP Xtreme Evolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257055/iterating-though-a-json-return-using-asp-xtreme-evolution)

I'm sure I had this working the other other day, but now I've come back to it, it's throwing a JScript error, and I can't seem to make it work now.

So, I'm posting JSON to a classic asp page, this is the code I'm using to include the json2.asp page as instructed in all the tutorials:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"%>
<!--#include file="json2.asp"-->"%>
<% 'json processing details here..
```

The error it throws is on a line of json2.asp and it's a JScript error.  Here is the exact error:

```
Microsoft JScript compilation error '800a03ea' 
Line 765 json2.asp
```

I believe this is a version of Crockfords json2.js and I think the reason it's in an asp page is so it can use JScript, but it's not progressing for me.  Anyone have any idea what I'm talking about that could help me out before I tear all my hair out?!

Let me know if you need more info - many thanks

UPDATE

Here is line 765 (in the middle between the comments)

```
if (/^[\],:{}\s]*$/.
test(text.replace(/\\(?:["\\\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g, '@').
replace(/"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g, ']').
replace(/(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g, ''))) {

// In the third stage we use the eval function to compile the text into a
// JavaScript structure. The '{' operator is subject to a syntactic ambiguity
// in JavaScript: it can begin a block or an object literal. We wrap the text
// in parens to eliminate the ambiguity.

        j = eval('(' + text + ')');

// In the optional fourth stage, we recursively walk the new structure, passing
// each name/value pair to a reviver function for possible transformation.

        return typeof reviver === 'function' ?
             walk({'': j}, '') : j;
}
```

Comment: check if the response you are processing is blank.

Comment: It would also help to know what line 765 is and some relevant code before/after it.

Comment: Ok, added the relevant code to the original post, but inexplicably, it has started working again. I've not touched it since this post last night, so I don't understand what happened! Thanks for looking anyway folks - I may be back when it decides not to play ball again!

Answer (score 0):

You're not including the right things.  You need the whole library available and to include the following files (change your paths appropriately).

```
<!-- #include file="includes/extlib/axe/base.asp" -->
<!-- #include file="includes/extlib/axe/classes/Parsers/json.class.asp" -->
```

Then to actually use, you do something like this:

```
set oJson = new Json
oJson.loadJson(strJSON)

strSomething = oJson.getElement("theElement")

set oJson = nothing
```

All this taken from working code.

Comment: No I don't think that's right. Like I said in the comment last night, it started working mysteriously after making no changes. It worked before, then wouldn't work at all, then started working again 24 hours later.  The working model doesn't include the whole library - the way I did it was recommended on other sites as a way of working without the bloat of adding the whole library just to parse json. Thanks though - I do appreciate the input all the same :)

Comment: This isn't loading the whole library, just the base and JSON parser.  I took it from working code, so it should solve your problems.  It's possible that it only needs access to functions in the base class occasionally and that is why you are seeing intermittent results.